# microphonic cable?

Tags: electric-guitar, cable

I am happy to say that I am learning all the time.  I have worked on my own guitars, electronics, etc.  I have replaced several PU's and am very comfortable with a soldering pencil.  I say all that to say I am not a complete noob.  That being said, I was very surprised to find out that 2 cables that I just purchased (on the cheap) are somewhat microphonic.  I don't know what brand they are.

[image]

To explain what I mean, if I plug in the cable to my amp and shake the cable, I will hear every ding and smack sound coming out of my amp.  No other cables, that I have, do that.  The cable is not broken and both of these do that.

Does anyone else have a similar experience?  Is this just poor shielding? Any suggestions on how to avoid this in the future?

Comment: This is off topic here - it is not about musical practice or theory.

Comment: Isn't equipment relevant to performance?  You can't remove cabling from audio.

Comment: Your post asks "Does anyone else have similar experience" which is completely off topic here. "Is this just poor shielding" - not a music question. "How to avoid this" also not in scope. This site doesn't just answer any question that has the vaguest connection with music - it answers questions within our tightly defined scope.

Comment: Don't worry Mayhem.  I won't make that mistake again.  I'm out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rule #1 - Don't buy cheap cables.

It's a capacitance issue in the cable itself, often caused by poor construction.
Surfaces rubbing together can create a similar effect to a condenser microphone, or by what is known as the [triboelectric effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect) [static, to us normal folks].

This from [Shure](https://service.shure.com/s/article/noise-problems-caused-by-audio-cable?language=en_US)

> **Handling Noise**
>
> This source of noise is induced as a result of changes in capacitance.
> When cables are bent, subjected to vibration, impacted, or crushed,
> the distance between conductors or between conductors and shields is
> changed. This results in a change of capacitance between conductors
> and that leads to changes in the voltage difference between
> conductors. A change in voltage will induce noise into the cable.
> Cables can be constructed with fillers where to give the cables
> strength, mechanical stability, and durability.
>
> **Static**
>
> Noise can be induced by the static build-up of electrons as a result
> of cables rubbing against each other or being dragged along carpets.
> The use of insulating material inside the cable shields can dissipate
> static noise, improve shield density, and further reduce noise
> inherent in normal handling.

Comment: Especially, don't use cheap cables for high impedance sources. A line-level source or condenser mic can easily power over a bit of triboelectric charge if the cable isn't all too long, but a passive electric guitar can't. (Of course cheap cables do have other issues as well, in particular reliability.)

Comment: To be completely honest, I thought they were inexpensive cables, not cheap cables.  Lesson learned.  :D